# Declare an array with custom data range in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, declare

I need to declare an array with custom data range in angular project.
Data range is described by combination of prefix letter A or F with number range: A001 - A069, F070 - F660, except "GND" - ground lvl and UNL - unlimited as first/last values. So the structure would look like this:

```
altitudeOptions[] = [GND], [A001],.. - ..,[A069], [AF70],.. - ..,[F660], [UNL]
```

I was thinking about delcare two arrays like this:

```
AltArrayA: number[] = [...Array(69).keys()].map(x => x + 1);
```

..and than add perfix letter, concat two Array A and F and than set GND and UNL as first and last element.

Please help me to do it in the optimal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `spread` operator to join arrays. In addition, it is possible to use `Array.from` where you can set length of an array. Based on length you can set zero signs:

```
const arr_A = Array.from({length: 69}, (v, k) => `A` +  ((k <= 8 ) ? '00' : '0') + (k + 1));
const arr_F = Array.from({length: 590}, (v, k) => `F` +  ((k < 30 ) ? '0' : '') + (k + 70));
const concatenated = ['GND', ...arr_A, 'AF70', ...arr_F, 'UNL'];
```

An example:

```js
const arr_A = Array.from({length: 69}, (v, k) => `A` +  ((k <= 8 ) ? '00' : '0') + (k + 1));
const arr_F = Array.from({length: 590}, (v, k) => `F` +  ((k < 30 ) ? '0' : '') + (k + 70));
const concatenated = ['GND', ...arr_A, 'AF70', ...arr_F, 'UNL'];
console.log(concatenated)
```

**UPDATE:**

This solution will give `O(n * 2)` complexity:

```js
const arr_A = Array.from({length: 69}, (v, k) => ( k % 5 == 0) ? 
        (`A` +  ((k <= 8 ) ? '00' : '0') + (k)) : null)
        .filter( f => f);
console.log(arr_A)
```

However, this solution will give `O(n)` complexity:

```js
const createArray = ( arrLength ) => {
  let fooArray = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < arrLength; index++) {
    if (index % 5 == 0)
      fooArray.push(`${index}`);
  }
  return fooArray;
}

console.log(createArray(69));
```

Comment: @Chrobry glad it helped to you:)

Comment: One more simple thing :) what if I would like to display only '05', '10', 15'...etc  values?